# Can I connect a WebRTC peer connection to Twilio and have the call bridged to PSTN or SIP?

Tags: webrtc, twilio

[Twilio has an example of taking SIP calls and connecting them to WebRTC.](https://www.siptowebrtc.com/) 
In this example the WebRTC client is a Twilio application.

Is there a similar capability to take WebRTC calls and bridge them to SIP calls? I am expecting to do the signaling for the peer connection between:

1. WebRTC endpoint running my application (*not* in a browser)
2. Twilio

After establishing the peer connection, I would like to instruct Twilio to make an outgoing phone call over SIP or PSTN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from Twilio via email regarding this question.

Only Twilio clients can be connected via WebRTC to the Twilio service. A Twilio client can have WebRTC bridged to SIP or PSTN.